# Gift Wrapping plugin for Woocommerce with conditional pricing

Tags: wordpress, plug-in, woocommerce

I need a plugin that provides a Gift Wrapping option to the checkout page with a specific price. I know there are thousands of them in the WordPress Plugin Directory, but I'm watching for one that can provide that gift wrapping for free when the amount of the cart is higher than a certain value.

In example: Gift wrapping costs 5$ for everyone, but if the customer buys products for more than 50$ value, gift wrapping is free.

Does anyone know one?